# Async Task gets Crashed when app is in background

Tags: android

I am Calling Asynctask to get response from the Json Service and setting the list in the post execute. Its working fine but when I open any other applications and then again open my app. I am getting NPE in the post execute. Any idea why its happening. Any Help Would be greatly appreciated.

```
    public class AsyncTaskParks extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        utility.showProgress(getActivity(), "Please Wait", "Loading..");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String response = mServiceHandler
                .getSoapResponseByMethod("GetSiteList");
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + response);

        if (response != null) {

            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray rows = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Rows");
                for (int i = 0; i < rows.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = rows.getJSONObject(i);

                    infoParks = new InfobeanParks();

                    String siteId = c.getString("SiteID");
                    infoParks.setSiteId(siteId);

                    String siteType = c.getString("SiteType");
                    infoParks.setSiteType(siteType);

                    String siteName = c.getString("SiteName");
                    infoParks.setSiteName(siteName);

                    String siteShortName = c.getString("SiteShortName");
                    infoParks.setSiteShortName(siteShortName);

                    String siteImage = c.getString("SiteImage");
                    infoParks.setSiteImage(siteImage);
                    if (siteType.equalsIgnoreCase("P")) {
                        lstPark.add(infoParks);

                    }

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        utility.dismissProgress();

        gridviewParks.setAdapter(new GridviewParksAdapter(getActivity(),
                lstPark));

    }
}
```

```
08-28 00:58:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(3720): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 00:58:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(3720): Process: com.oceancity.ocparks, PID: 3720
08-28 00:58:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(3720): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-28 00:58:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(3720):     at      com.ocparks.adapter.GridviewParksAdapter.<init>(GridviewParksAdapter.java:47)
08-28 00:58:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(3720):     at    com.ocparks.FragmentParks$AsyncTaskParks.onPostExecute(FragmentParks.java:201)
08-28 00:58:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(3720):     at com.ocparks.FragmentParks$AsyncTaskParks.onPostExecute(FragmentParks.java:1)
08-28 00:58:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(3720):     at   android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
08-28 00:58:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(3720):     at    android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-28 00:58:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(3720):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
08-28 00:58:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(3720):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-28 00:58:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(3720):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-28 00:58:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(3720):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
08-28 00:58:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(3720):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 00:58:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(3720):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-28 00:58:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(3720):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-28 00:58:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(3720):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-28 00:58:15.911: E/AndroidRuntime(3720):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is `gridviewParks`? and how find it? post your complete code.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the views of an inactive `Activity`. You need to check that the `Activity` is still running in the `onPostExecute` or better yet, just cancel the `ASyncTask` completely in the onPause or onStop methods.

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mAsyncTaskParks != null){
        mAsyncTaskParks.cancel();
     }
}
```

The benefit of this second method is that it will call `ASyncTask's` `onCancelled` method which will allow you to cancel the network call, if that's what you want to do.

Comment: No It did not worked. The app gets crashed as soon as I pushed it in to the background.

Comment: cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)  ... true if the thread executing this task should be interrupted; otherwise, in-progress tasks are allowed to complete.

Comment: Are you running this inside a fragment?

Comment: I tried but its not working. Any Suggestion why it is coming NPE?

Comment: The problem is inside the GridviewParksAdapter init method. It's most likely because getActivity() is null. This would happen if the fragment is no longer attached to the activity (ie replaced or ended, or in background) add a check for null or use Fragment's isDetached() method to check if the fragment is still attached to activity

Comment: I used  onDetach() Method to cancel the Task. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.